# proper time span expressions between two-day work and two days of work

Tags: measure-expressions

Which one of the following time span expressions is proper "two-day work" or "two days of work"?

Comment: What's the *context?* We'd normally say that *a two-day **job*** is expected to require *two days of **work*** to complete, but at a pinch you could describe a painting or something as *a two-day work* if it took the artist two days to complete it.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  Thank you for your clarification. I wanted to know preferred way of using time span with "of" or without "of" such as "a few hours of reading book", "three hours of trip"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Two days" is a time span.
"Two calendar days" is also a time span, and it clarifies that you mean two days "on the calendar", in other words, you are including holidays and other non-business days (maybe Saturdays, Sundays, etc.)
"Two working days" and even "two work days" are time spans that only include days when the office is open or that people are working.

The phrase you mention, "two days of work", along with "two days *worth* of work", and "two days' work" aren't really *time spans*. These are phrases that describe an amount of work (based on how long the job takes or is *expected* to take). For example, you could say,

> "You're going to have to pay for two days of work for my whole crew."

or

> "You guys have been coming in every day for the past month, and you
>   only got two days of work done."

or

> He's our most valuable employee. Every morning he finishes two whole days of
>   work, and then he goofs off the rest of the day.

"Two day work" is not usually grammatically correct. You could talk about a "two day work week"  or a "two-day work week", but in this case "two day" would be an adjective describing the "work week", and "two day work" isn't really an idiomatic expression by itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found this phrase "two-day weekend", so, as you suggested `two-day` is an adjective?

Comment: @kenn an 'adjective phrase' I think it would be called (*functions* as an adjective anyway"